# How to trigger function when control is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work on my angularjs project.

Here is my cotroller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("dashboard").controller('dashboardController', ["$scope", "dashboardServices", dashboardController]);

    function dashboardController($scope, dashboardServices) {

        $scope.month = new Date().getMonth()+1;
        $scope.year = new Date().getFullYear();         

        $scope.getRecords = function () {
            dashboardServices.getRecords($scope.year, $scope.month).then(function (response) {
                var result = dashboardServices.convert2json(response.data);
                $scope.report = result.ArrayOfDepartmentReport;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

How to make function  `$scope.getRecords` to be triggered when controll is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Execution of your controller code happens only when the controller is loaded.

Put `$scope.getRecords()` at the bottom of the controller.